# How To Check To See If A Concept Is A Child Of Itself

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology

I'm linking a number of ontology models, all with a shared base model where all classes and relationships are defined.  Each model was created by a different developer and have overlapping domains.  I need to check to make sure that no circular references have been made.  Such as A has a child B, B has C and then, by accident, C has the child A.  It's possible in our software to achieve this without error.  I have written SPARQL that catches A has child B and simultaneously B has child A, but I'm not sure how to resolve the first issue. Thanks.

EDIT:
I need to detect any recursion in my linked model.  So, when linking multiple ontologies, there is the potential, in this aggregate model, where the following can occur:

```
A
 \
  B
   \
    C
     \
      A
```

This obviously creates an issue in the end application if I have an infinite recursive loop.  My apologies if I was initially unclear.

Comment: What is "concept" and what is "is a child"? Post your first query at least... Let's suppose it looks like `SELECT ?a ?b {?a :has_child ?b . ?b :has_child ?a}`? It seems that after removing these 2-circles your could simply write `SELECT ?a ?b ?c {?a :has_child ?b . ?b :has_child ?c. ?c :has_child ?a}` Before removing, you should add something like `FILTER (?a != ?c)`. Or possibly you could involve inferencing: make `:has_child` transitive and irreflexive, then check consistency.

Comment: @StanislavKralin I think he's talking about class hierarchy in RDF, thus, `rdfs:subClassOf` might be the relation to go.

Comment: SPARQL 1.1 property paths can be used

Comment: @AKSW, then the OP forbids equivalent classes, that is strange...

Comment: @StanislavKralin yes, by definition it's a cycle as well but maybe this case should be allowed. but we don't know his use case or requirements nor the "child" relation. I'm also sure that property paths might not scale for very large ontologies with a deep hierarchy. from what I know and learned, checking for cycles is expensive in SPARQL if even possible. graph databases provide better support here, but if the data is small I'd go for property paths first.

Comment: Hello Juston, Please don't add tags in titles, like "SPARQL:" unless it actually forms part of your question. The tags are already included at the bottom of your question. For information as to why we remove tags from titles, [see this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/363946).

Comment: @Davy M  Thanks for the heads up.  Someone had edited it out and didn't know why.  Still kind of new here...  Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[SPARQL 1.1 Property Paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) seem the obvious solution, if you know what predicates are involved.  For example, for classes and subclasses, I'd do something like --

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?selfParent
WHERE 
  { ?selfParent rdfs:subClassOf+ ?selfParent }
```

***Note:*** As of this writing, there is a bug in Virtuoso's query optimizer, which prevents execution of the above `OneOrMorePath` (the `+` operator) query.  You can work around this with the equivalent `SequencePath` of `One` followed by `ZeroOrMorePath` (the `*` operator) below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?selfParent
WHERE 
  { ?selfParent rdfs:subClassOf / 
                rdfs:subClassOf* ?selfParent }
```

You can also execute (and/or `UNION`) multiple `SequencePath` queries with varying depths, as below.  With this method, you might specify different predicates at each level.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?selfParent
WHERE 
  { { ?selfParent rdfs:subClassOf ?selfParent }
    UNION
    { ?selfParent rdfs:subClassOf / 
                  rdfs:subClassOf ?selfParent }
    UNION
    { ?selfParent rdfs:subClassOf / 
                  rdfs:subClassOf / 
                  rdfs:subClassOf ?selfParent }
  }
```

If you have multiple predicate which might appear at some level, you might change that instance of `rdfs:subClassOf` to `( rdfs:subClassOf | ex:myPredicate )`, as in --

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?selfParent
WHERE 
  { { ?selfParent rdfs:subClassOf ?selfParent }
    UNION
    { ?selfParent rdfs:subClassOf / 
                  rdfs:subClassOf ?selfParent }
    UNION
    { ?selfParent rdfs:subClassOf / 
                  ( rdfs:subClassOf | ex:myPredicate ) / 
                  rdfs:subClassOf ?selfParent }
  }
```

These results won't show you the complete paths, but I presume you can work them out from here.